# List classrooms for organisation

Tags: google-classroom

I'm really new to this but I need to get a list of Classrooms with teachers for an organisation.  I have run the quickstart script provided by Google but this only shows the classrooms I am attached to.

Does anyone have the code to run this for the whole organisation?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `Courses.list()` request as a domain administrator then you'll have access to all the courses within the domain.